# How to extend Distributed availability groups to another datacenter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, high-availability, distributed-availability-groups

Actually I have a Distributed availability groups with SQL Server 2016 configured like this:
[image]

The endpoint are configured like this:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE ENDPOINT [endpoint_istance2]
    STATE=STARTED
    AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 5022, LISTENER_IP=ALL)
    FOR DATA_MIRRORING (ROLE=ALL,AUTHENTICATION=WINDOWS NEGOTIATE,ENCRYPTION=REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES)
GO
 
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::[endpoint_istance2] TO [mydomain\sqlmirrorer]
GO
```

Now, I need to add another datacenter, not in the same Microsoft Domain. I need to obtain this:

[image]

- This third AG is in WORKGROUP.
- I cannot add a trust.

I can imagine two ways:

1. Is it possible to have a mixed authentication on the enpoint? I know I cannot have multiple endpoints on one instance.
2. Do I need to alter every endpoint to go with certificate only? How can I do it without breaking the DAG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a mixed authentication on the enpoint? I know I cannot have multiple endpoints on one instance.

Correct, only a single endpoint, but it's possible to have multiple authenticators on a single endpoint.

Example:

```
CREATE ENDPOINT My_Hadr_Endpoint 
AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 2100)
FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING
(
    AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS NEGOTIATE CERTIFICATE MyCert,
    ENCRYPTION = SUPPORTED ALGORITHM AES,
    ROLE = ALL
)
```

> Do I need to alter every endpoint to go with certificate only? How can I do it without breaking the DAG?

In your diagram above, the only endpoint that would need changed is the one on Cluster B, which would be to add a certificate as an extra authenticator.

Comment: Perfetc, it works! Thank you.